# Chrome not triggering jquery .hover() without having clicked somewhere on the page first

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So this question may have been asked in many different ways but not in a way that it will help me figure the problem out.

I'm currently working on an application which will use a login button that gets activated when some validation requirements are met. This works all fine and dandy untill the browser uses autofill. I managed to create a sort of work around for Firefox and for what I thought Chrome.

The code I've used to trigger the validation of the fields is this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("div").hover(function(){
    validate();
    $('#email, #passwd').keyup(validate);
    });
});
```

As you might have guessed Chrome is trying to throw a fit with me and only reacts to a .hover() event after I've clicked somewhere on the page. I've tried to trigger it without the ready but that also won't work. Firefox isn't giving any problem with this whatsoever.

It's bugging me and I know this has been a problem with Chrome for a while now, I'm only interested in fixing this. One way or another I'm gonna beat Chrome, this has gotten personal.

For reference the website is the following: [website](https://test.weper4mens.nl/)

Update: So after a few comments I've altered the js a bit. I'm back with the div because it works with the example supplied by Shubham. Removed the tooltip from the page so the error is gone but now I'm stuck with an Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function. And that everytime it's triggered by entering or leaving a div. Complete and updated code down below.

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    validate();
    $('#email, #passwd').validate();
    alert("test");
    });

$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#email, #passwd').keyup(validate);
});
function validate(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
    if (lastPart === "wwvergeten=1") {
        if ($('#email').val().length   >=   3) {
            $("#wwvergeten").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#wwvergeten").css("background", "rgba(36,183,56,1)");

        }
        else {
            $("#wwvergeten").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#wwvergeten").css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($('#email').val().length   >=   3   &&
            $('#passwd').val().length  >=   6) {
            $("#inloggen").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#inloggen").css("background", "rgba(36,183,56,1)");

        }
        else {
            $("#inloggen").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#inloggen").css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _gonna beat Chrome_....seems a bug.

Comment: I just tested in chrome, working fine for me. Open this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fjm37ptb/1/) in chrome.

Comment: Hmm @Shubham weird, not sure why it's not working for me

Comment: Changed the trigger from div to an id given to the yellow container but it"s not working yet

Comment: (index):38 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function(…), when running your website in chrome. You can see this in console.

you have used this  $('.jqtooltip').tooltip({  somewhere.

Comment: @ManojLodhi Found the code, not mine. From one of the previous developers. Removed it for this page, might be in use somewhere else. Still not fixing the problem sadly

Comment: Now I'm getting the is not a function on the validate function..

Comment: @J.vanderEem seems like you have other issues in your page, check the console and clear all the errors, your `hover()` is not working because of the other scripts that break the execution due to error

Comment: You do have a jQuery validate plugin, right? Otherwise `$('#email, #passwd').validate();` won't work.